# laravel routing / How i can use array of parameters in route

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to use this route

Route::get('/myapi/params/{param11},{param2}/producers/{producer1},{producer2}', 'MyApiController@index');

I try to use different params and producers values in route. And it's may be 1,2,3 or more values for params

Can I use it's in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should merge them into a single parameter

```php
Route::get(
    '/myapi/params/{params}/producers/{producers}', 'MyApiController@index'
);
```

And in a controller method for example:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function checkParams(Request $request)
{
    $route = $request->route();
    $params = explode(',', $route->param('params'));
    $producers = explode(',', $route->param('producers'));
}
```

Therefore you get an ordered array with all your params/producers, whatever how many.

Comment: it's work   $route = $request->route();
    $params = explode(',', $route->parameters('params')['param']);
    $producers = explode(',', $route->parameters('producers')['producer']);

Answer (score 0):

You can't used `,` inside route. So You can use route like

```
Route::get('/myapi/params/{param11}/{param2}/producers/{producer1}/{producer2}', 'MyApiController@index');
```

It will work for you.